# pycurl is working in an unexpected way

Tags: python, html, tor, pycurl

I have written  a code that visits a URL using pycurl. I have tor enabled.
The URL gets redirected to some other url.

Below is the code.

```
import pycurl
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, URL)
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, '127.0.0.1')
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050)
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0')
curl.perform()
```

It prints the expected html content.
But whenever there is a visit to a URL, there is an increment to a count somewhere else.

Now, when I run the script, I get the html content, but there is no increment in the count, but when the same html output is run in some online html rendering website(htmledit.squarefree.com/
), the count is incremented.

Any help to increment the count automatically, using the script itself?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the url that you're calling and what is this count you're talking about?

Comment: It is some general URL like http://www.ohohohoho.com/kTdmJ and whenever I visit this URL, it needs to update some count I am keeping.

Comment: and why are you using tor? it doesn't seem like its counting unique ip.

Comment: I am actually making a bot to increment the count anonymously.

Comment: What is updating the counter? If it is some javascript, you won't be able to make it work using only `curl`.

Comment: Yes, it is some javascript, do you know some work around?

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of updation of some data on server when client visit their website is possibly done through javascript.

When some website content is loaded on client machine, it has got some javascript, which gets executed onto client's machine to notify the server. Now when the webpage is visited through browser, javascript are executed(if the browser is enabled to do it). But when the webpage is visited through curl, it can't execute javascript.

I managed to do it using [dryscrape](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Dryscrape uses http protocol. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425180/how-to-set-socks5-proxy-in-dryscrape-python) for work around to enable socks5 protocol for dryscrape.