# How to set socks5 proxy in dryscrape python?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, tor

I want to scrap some website through tor.

Tor works uses socks proxy. 
I use dryscrape(library in python) as it also executes javascripts as well.

But I dryscrape can have only http proxy.

Is there some work around to set socks5 proxy for dryscrape or any other way out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using [polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/). It can be installed on ubuntu from [here](https://www.stormfront.org/forum/t807851/).

Polipo can speak socks protocol as well as http protocol.
Polipo can be configured to receive requests through http proxy and forward the same requests through socks5 proxy.

I used it as a front-end proxy server to dryscrape, for the back-end tor proxy server.

So, now I set dryscrape's http proxy 127.0.0.1(machine ip) and port no. 8118(default port no. for polipo).
Now, Polipo forwards the same request to tor through socks5 proxy.

So, now I can use dryscrape to make request through socks5 proxy.

It is explained in more detail over [here](https://www.techromance.com/2015/09/15/set-socks5-proxy-dryscrape-python/).
;)